# Node Module command from PHP exec() not working

Tags: php, node.js, mamp, node-modules

From Terminal this works just fine and returns what is expected:

```
/Users/me/Desktop/Clients/IM/apps/node_modules/.bin/mjml newslettercode.html
```

This also works just fine from Terminal

```
node node_modules/.bin/mjml newslettercode.html
```

This also works just fine from Terminal

```
node_modules/.bin/mjml newslettercode.html
```

Im running MAMP & domain as my development.

From my .php file in my browser i get exec() error 127 and no output.

This test code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

define('ROOT_DIR', realpath(__DIR__.'/..'));

$file =  ROOT_DIR.'/apps/node_modules/.bin/mjml newslettercode.html';

exec($file, $output, $responseCode);

print_r ($file);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($responseCode);
echo "</pre>";
```

Returns this:

```
/Users/me/Desktop/Clients/IM/apps/node_modules/.bin/mjml newslettercode.html

Array
(
)

127
```

Im assuming that Node is not running on My MAMP Host?  im not sure.. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure That you using the direct path of the application , it sounds like php can't find the application.

Comment: try exec('/usr/bin/node node_modules/.bin/mjml newslettercode.html')

Comment: @HamzaNig i tried both and didnt work.  Sidenote... i looked in 'usr/bin' and i dont see any "node"

Comment: @HamzaNig  changed it to '/usr/local/bin/node'  and it worked... thanks for pointing me in the right direction... now wondering how that will translate/work when pushing to production.

Comment: yeah great then you welcome brother , usually /usr/bin/node is the default path but sames are changed on your platform  nice try good Job  , i will add it as an answer to help people directly without searching on comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem Was in path of the aplication php can't find the application by using just `node /../..php`  try to use the command bellow should make the work  :

> @HamzaNig : /usr/bin/node mostly is the default path
>
> @Joe      : /usr/local/bin/node is the default path on his platform